# In Ckeditor, delete br tags before and after the text

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

When the users paste text in the editor (for example), they don't delete the spaces before and after the text.

How to remove these `br` tags? It would work like the `trim()` function in php.

My code is:

```
    CKEDITOR.replace('contenido',
    {
       language: 'es',
       resize_enabled: true,
       pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles: true,
       pasteFromWordPromptCleanup: true,
       forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
       ignoreEmptyParagraph: true,
       removeFormatAttributes: true,
       autoParagraph: false,
       fillEmptyBlocks: false,
       enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
       toolbar: [
         ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
         ['Cut', 'Copy', 'PasteText', '-', 'Scayt'],
         ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'], ['CreateDiv', '-', 'ShowBlocks'],
         ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote'],
         ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
         ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar'], ['Source'],['Maximize']
 ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use a built in PHP method to do this for you take a look at this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

You can use the second pram of the method to list any html type tags you don't want trimmed away.  So in theory if you only want "
" removed you could give it a list of every tag but that one.

Hope this helps.